# add information to class with each trait or child

Tags: php, oop

Lets say I have a class which holds an array

```
class A {
  protected $list = [1];
}
```

Then I want to add information to the instances via traits or extending classes.

```
trait B {
  protected $list = [2, 3];
}

class C extends A {
  protected $list = [4];
}
```

Then if I construct something like this

```
$d = new class extends C {
  use B;

  protected $list = [5];
}
```

I would need the list to be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` instead of `[5]`. Obviously this is not the way to go I just used it to illustrate what I need to do. The problem is that I do not know how many traits or inherits there will be since I'm only designing the parent class. I got tempted to use the constructor but if there are multiple traits it gets ugly really quick.

Comment: I think this is a misuse of traits, and the reason that it's so hard to accomplish in this way should be a powerful code-smell that what you are doing is not such a great idea, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way to do it in PHP.

From the top of my head, you can accomplish more or less the same thing in, for example, Ruby, where everything is an object (including the class itself) and you can overwrite or hook on methods like `extend`.

But in PHP consider using something like [Decorator Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator/php):

```
interface HasList
{
    public function list(): array;
}

class A implements HasList
{
    private $list = [1];

    public function list(): array
    {
        return $this->list;
    }
}

class B implements HasList {
    private $list = [2, 3];

    private $objectToDecorate;

    public function __construct(HasList $objectToDecorate)
    {
        $this->objectToDecorate = $objectToDecorate;
    }

    public function list(): array
    {
        return array_merge($this->objectToDecorate->list(), $this->list);       
    }
}

$list = (new B(new A))->list();
```